# WSO2 ESB (4.9.0) throw out SOAPProcessingException when connecting Salesforce through proxy server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I try to use WSO2 ESB at workplace where Proxy Server is available.

1. Set Proxy Server settings in axis2.xml,

[image]

2. Install certificate.

   [image: certificate]
3. Initialize Salesforce connector(Salesforce certificate has been installed).

[image]

4. Test the API, run into an exception - SOAPProcessingException,

[image: output2]

[image: output1]

[image]

Really appreciate if someone can give ideas of solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have tried this type of a scenario using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and which was perfectly working fine. By looking at your error messages I can see that there was an Authentication failure, hence Sales Force end point returns some HTML error message. The ESB tries to build this HTML error message using the SOAP builder leading to this situation.

This could be due to some missing configuration in your setting. You may follow [1] to enable HTTP Proxy to Sales Force. Then to setup Sales Force [2] will be helpful.

Couple of thing I need to highlight here. Did you import the Salesforce certificate into the ESBs client trust store using the keytool import command. If not please go ahead and do so. Also is there a particular reason for you to use NHTTP transport here. Ideally we would use Passthrough transport to add the proxy host as given in [1].

If you still get the error after following the above steps please enable the wirelogs and post it here to investigate further. Follow these steps to enable wirelogs.

1. Open log4j.properties file from a text editor.
   log4j.properties file is located in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory.
2. Un-comment the following entry.
   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG

Hope this helps you.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Enabling+SSL+Tunneling+through+a+Proxy+Server

[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Salesforce+Connector+Operations

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have installed certificates at first place. I updated the question so you can see the output console, said "Credentials are missing" and seems the credentials are not pass through at all.

Comment: I just found the proxy server is only working for http instead of https. for example: 1)  <loginUrl>http://XXX.XXX.com</loginUrl> can pass the proxy server; 2) <loginUrl>https://XXX.XXX.com</loginUrl> will fail to pass proxy server